# Multithreading - how to stop all threads if condition is met?

Tags: c, multithreading

EDIT : I **cannot** use mutex or sleep() or any type of waiting as we're fairly new to threads in C.

For my assignment I'm to make a *bruteforce password cracker* using threads. The idea is that I have the hash and salt of a password so I have use a combination of the alphabet A-Z, a-z, 0-9 and encrypt it using the crypt_r function and compare it with the hash and salt I have.

I created 2 threads, one that just checks for lowercase letters and the second one that checks all the letters of the alphabet.

My problem is that once the lowercase thread finds the password it gives it but the second thread continues running in the background.

**How can I stop the second thread without using any global variables?**

Here's how I go about the thread joins :

```
for (int i = 0; i < nbThread; ++i) {
    pthread_join(tabThread[i], NULL);
    pthread_join(tabThread2[i], NULL);
}
```

Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop a running pthread thread?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18826853/how-to-stop-a-running-pthread-thread)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't *have* to use `pthread_join()` calls unless you want to do something after the threads exit. It's a convenience function, not a necessity. You can let the main thread exit with `pthread_exit()` (without any `pthead_join()` calls) and the other two threads can continue until either of them succeeded. If either of your threads find the password then you can simply exit (using `_exit()` or `_Exit()`) the process and the other thread will naturally be terminated on process exit.

Comment: thank you ! in my thread I added a "if password is found -> pthread_exit(NULL)" and it seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

Well you have [`pthread_cancel`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_cancel.html) which is the nice way of telling a thread that it's time to exit. The threads needs to be aware of the possibility of cancellation, and handle it appropriately.

And then you have the not-nice-at-all way of just killing the thread with [`pthread_killl`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_kill.html). Note that using `pthread_kill` could lead to resource leaks.

Comment: Can I call pthread_cancel within the thread? I pass a struct to my thread but the struct doesn't contain a pointer to the thread.

Comment: @JohnLivingston If you have the `pthread_t` of the thread you want to cancel, then you can call it from anywhere.